# Rudin's RCA Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

While I was reading the proof of the theorem of Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym presented in the Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, there is a part I cannot catch the point clearly. It says:

> > (1) Observe how the completeness of $L^2(\phi)$ was used to guarantee the existence of $g$. (2) Observe also that although $g$ is defined uniquely as an element of $L^2(\phi)$, $g$ is determined only a.e. $[\phi]$ as a point function on $X$.

Firstly, I guess that the completeness of $L^2(\phi)$ is necessary to apply Theorem 4.10:

> > Every nonempty, closed, convex set $E$ in a Hilbert space $H$ contains a unique element of smallest norm.

Then, we can apply Theorem 4.11 and 4.12 to guarantee that there exists a unique $g\in L^2(\phi)$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\int_Xfd\lambda = \int_Xfgd\phi
\end{equation*}
for every $f\in L^2(\phi)$.
It seems quite obvious, so I am not certain if it is all meant in the first sentence.

Secondly, it is quite confusing to understand the meaning of "as a point function on $X$" in the second sentence. I understand that the set of equivalence classes of $L^2(\phi)$ is a Hilbert space, so the uniqueness actually applies to the equivalence class of $g$. Then, what does "as a point function on $X$" mean? Does it mean as a point on $L^2(\phi)$ or as a constant function on X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your interpretation of the first part. Completeness of $L^2$ is used to guarantee the existence of $g$.

For the second part, if Rudin writes "as a point function", he means "as an honest-to-god *pointwise defined* function", that is, without identifying functions that agree almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Probably, Rudin wanted to clarify that $g$ is a specific function which is a member of the unique equivalence class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I think the completeness of $L^2(\phi)$ is being used. To use Theorem $4.12$, we require $L$ to be a continuous linear functional. In the proof you mention, we have shown $L$ to be a bounded linear functional. We can use Theorem $5.4$ to conclude that bounded $\Longleftrightarrow$ continuous, since all Hilbert spaces are Banach spaces (hence normed linear spaces) and $\mathbb R$ is a normed linear space too.